# Why does calling CreateFileMapping() with a 1K size result in 64K of Virtual Memory usage?

Tags: windows, memory-management

My 32-bit Windows program passes a 1K size to [CreateFileMappingA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga), the virtual memory [VMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap#:%7E:text=VMMap%20is%20a%20process%20virtual,operating%20system%20to%20those%20types.) shows a size 4K with a gap of 0x10000 (64K) between memory maps.

[image: vmmap]

Overall, there are ~30,000 maps resulting in ~2GB (30,000 x 64K) of virtual memory usage.

I was expecting ~120MB (30,000 x 4K) memory usage, not 2GB leading to 'out of memory' issues!

**Question**

Are there any tips / tricks or flags to reduce the memory footprint?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031008-00/?p=42223

Comment: That link refers to VirtualAlloc(). So, I assume CreateFileMapping() invokes that API under the hood?

Comment: Allocation granularity is a global constraint, not just for VirtualAlloc specifically.